# Rendered object looks flat even with shadows

Tags: three.js

I'm a `three.js` newb. I've been playing around with it for a couple of days and haven't been able to figure out how to make my objects look more realistic. I suspect there's no simple answer for this question, but is there anything I can do to improve my rendering quality without going into the depth of "rendering science"? Maybe I'm missing some configs. Thank you for any advice!

Here's the relevant code used in rendering a kitchen cabinet frame.

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
this.renderer.setSize(this.container.offsetWidth, this.container.offsetHeight)
this.renderer.sortObjects = false
this.renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0)
this.renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2
this.renderer.gammaOutput = true
this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.8)
const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.3)
light2.position.set(400, 400, 400)
light2.shadow.camera.near = 10
light2.shadow.camera.far = 10000
light2.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048
light2.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048
light2.castShadow = true
this.scene.add(light2)
this.scene.add(light)

const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, metalness: 0, roughness: 0 })
```

[image]

Comment: Did you export your model with normals? It looks like it doesn't have normals, and your material could also use an [`envMap`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.envMap)

Comment: @Marquizzo, the model is made out of a bunch of BoxBufferGeometries

Comment: Oh, then it's probably your renderer's gamma settings. It might be blowing out all lighting nuance due to overexposure. Try bringing them down a bit, or maybe just turning it off while you adjust your lights.

Comment: Can you post your code in a running snippet?

Comment: I added a runnable code snippet below that you can use as a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let scene, camera, controls, ambient, point, loader, renderer, container, stats;

const targetRotation = 0;
const targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;
const mouseX = 0;
const mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;
const windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


init();
animate();
var box, b1, b2, b3;

function init() {
  // Create a scene which will hold all our meshes to be rendered
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Create and position a camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
     60, // Field of view
     window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // Aspect ratio
    /*window.innerWidth / -8,
    window.innerWidth / 8,
    window.innerHeight / 8,
    window.innerHeight / -8,
    */
    0.1, // Near clipping pane
    1000 // Far clipping pane
  );
scene.add(camera)
  // Reposition the camera
  camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
  // Point the camera at a given coordinate
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  // Add orbit control
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.target.set(0, -0.5, 0);
  controls.update();

  // Add an ambient lights
  ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
  scene.add(ambient);

  // Add a point light that will cast shadows
  point = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
  point.position.set(25, 50, 25);
  point.castShadow = true;
  point.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  point.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  scene.add(point);

  group = new THREE.Group();
  group.position.y = 0;
  scene.add(group);
  rotationAnchor = new THREE.Object3D()
  group.add(rotationAnchor);

  box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(), new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 'grey'
  }))
  b1 = box.clone();
  b2 = box.clone();
  b3 = box.clone();
  b3.material = b3.material.clone()
  b3.material.color.set('red')
  group.add(box);
  group.add(b1);
  b1.position.y += 1
  group.add(b2);
  b2.position.z += 1
  rotationAnchor.add(b3);
  rotationAnchor.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 1.5)
  b3.position.set(-.5, -.5, -.5)
  // Create a renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  // Set size
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Set color
  renderer.setClearColor(0xf8a5c2);
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;
  // Enable shadow mapping
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

  // Append to the document
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  // Add resize listener
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

  // Enable FPS stats
  stats = new Stats();
  container.appendChild(stats.dom);

  var gui = new dat.GUI({
    height: 5 * 32 - 1
  });
  let params = {
    'test': 4,
    'bevelThickness': 1,
    'bevelSize': 1.5,
    'bevelSegments': 3
  }
  gui.add(params, 'test', 0, 10).onChange(val => {
    test = val
  })
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  rotationAnchor.rotation.z = (Math.cos(performance.now() * 0.001) * Math.PI * 0.25) + (Math.PI * 1.25)
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // Re-render scene
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // Update stats
  stats.update();
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.2/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```